# Select all rows in table1 and all matched rows in table2 in same row based on ID

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

1. UserInfo
2. ContactInfo

My table structure is as below:

**UserInfo**

```
 UserId   Name
 1        Sandeep
 2        James
 3        Vishal
```

**ContactInfo**

```
    Id UserId   Email             Mobile 
    1  1        e1@somemail.com   111111
    2  1        e2@somemail.com   222222
    3  3        v1@somemail.com   010101
```

Now i'm looking for result like below

**Result**

```
    UserId UserName   Email1          Mobile1   Email2          Mobile2
      1    Sandeep    e1@somemail.com 111111    e2@somemail.com 222222
      2    James      NULL            NULL      NULL             NULL
      3    Vishal     v1@somemail.com 010101    NULL             NULL
```

**Note:** One to many relationship between `UserInfo` and `ContactInfo`

Can anyone help me to get it done? Your response are highly appreciated.

Comment: How  many records for the same `UserId` can you have in `ContactInfo` table?

Comment: @Felix LOL I just tried adding another DB tag and apparently SO limits to 5 tags.  This is why he stopped ^ ^

Comment: I deleted my comment as I'm not sure if I listed all dbms. =)

Comment: Do a left a left or right join between the 2 tables.

Comment: @dotnetom No limit for ContactInfo per user. User can have any number of ContactInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [**dynamic crosstab**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/) to achieve this.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
      u.UserId
    , u.Name' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), rn) +' THEN t.Email END) AS ' 
        + QUOTENAME('Email' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), rn)) + CHAR(10) +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), rn) +' THEN t.Mobile END) AS ' 
        + QUOTENAME('Mobile' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), rn)) + CHAR(10)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Id)
    FROM ContactInfo
)t
-- Add filter here for ROW_NUMBER, e.g. starting from the 25th row to 50th
WHERE rn BETWEEN 25 AND 50

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM UserInfo u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Id)
    FROM ContactInfo
)t
    ON t.UserId = u.UserId
    -- Add filter here for ROW_NUMBER, e.g. starting from the 25th row to 50th
    AND rn BETWEEN 25 AND 50
GROUP BY u.UserId, u.Name
ORDER BY u.UserId, u.Name'

PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/448048)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Felix, It's working great. My result have more than 300k rows, So i'm fetching records by chunks like 25k rows one chunk. Now i need to get Row_NUMBER() of ContactInfo table for those 25k rows only. Is there any way to get ROW_NUMBER() from the fetching rows?
FYI: I'm using "offset 25000 rows FETCH NEXT 25000 ROWS ONLY" to fetch data from DB

Comment: for example like this http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/448691

Comment: @sandeepnagabhairava, see my edit, take note of the comments.

Comment: I need maximum ROW_NUMBER of ContactInfo from selecting Users.
If you see this example once you can exactly know what i'm looking for
http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/448691

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your question. I suggest you open a new one.

Comment: @ felix,  i opened new one. you can get it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931883/select-maximum-number-of-repeated-userid-in-table-contactinfo-from-selected-us

Answer (score 2):

Your tables aren't really structured very well.  For example, what if your user has one email but two mobile numbers?  Which mobile number are you associating with the email? This association has no meaning.  These are all accurate representations of this data in its current form:

1.

```
ID | UserId | Email     | Mobile
1  | 1      | a@a.com   | 111111
2  | 1      | NULL      | 222222
```

2.

```
ID | UserId | Email     | Mobile
1  | 1      | NULL      | 111111
2  | 1      | a@a.com   | 222222
```

3.

```
ID | UserId | Email     | Mobile
1  | 1      | NULL      | 111111
2  | 1      | NULL      | 222222
3  | 1      | a@a.com   | NULL
```

Instead, consider a structure like this:

```
ID | UserId | Type      | Mobile
1  | 1      | Mobile    | 111111
2  | 1      | Mobile    | 222222
3  | 1      | Email     | a@a.com
```

There are other improvements to make as well, but I digress.  To answer your question in its current state, the following query should work:

```
SELECT     U.Name,
           CI1.Email as Email1,
           CI1.Mobile as Mobile1,
           CI2.Email as Email2,
           CI2.Mobile as Mobile2

FROM       UserInfo U

LEFT JOIN  (
           SELECT   UserID,
                    Email,
                    Mobile,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY ID) as row
           FROM     ContactInfo
           ) CI1
ON         U.UserID = CI1.UserID
AND        CI1.row = 1


LEFT JOIN  (
           SELECT   UserID,
                    Email,
                    Mobile,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY ID) as row
           FROM     ContactInfo
           ) CI2
ON         U.UserID = CI1.UserID
AND        CI1.row = 2
```

Comment: Can we get all ContactInfo information for UserId in one row?

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to.  If you're using it in an application, you are better off outputting one row per user per contact and handling it in some well-defined CLR in the application itself.  Plus, without defining exactly how many emails and mobile numbers any given user CAN have, you have no concrete structure to base a query or object around.

Comment: I need to bind the result to excel sheet to export

Comment: There is no good way to do this.  Someone might argue that you could use dynamic SQL with a PIVOT operator, but that's waaaay too complex for your simple use case.  Think about your request again: a user can have any number of contacts?  What if the user has 20 contacts? 200?  2,000,000?  That's a ridiculous excel spreadsheet.  And then how does your user use the data?  Do you expect them to select all the data out of multiple columns?  Yuck.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your support,But my user requirement is like that only.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, and you simply want to display the ContactInfo record with the lowest Id with each given user, I'd do something like the following:

```
SELECT  ci.UserId, ui.Name AS UserName, ci.*
  FROM  UserInfo ui
 INNER  JOIN (
        SELECT  ci.UserId AS UserId, MIN(ci.Id) AS Id
          FROM  ContactInfo ci
         GROUP  BY ci.UserId
        ) AS q ON (q.UserId = ui.UserId)
 INNER  JOIN ContactInfo ci ON (ci.Id = q.Id)
```

EDIT:
Using OVER PARTITION BY often works as well, but I typically prefer to use nested queries as they usually have better execution plans.

Comment: Feel free to modify the joins accordingly. For example, my answer assumes that there always will be at least one ContactInfo record for every UserInfo record, so therefore INNER JOIN works perfectly. If you have the possibility of having no ContactInfo record for a given UserInfo record but still want to return the UserInfo record, replace the above INNER JOINs with LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I know this comment doesn't belong here, but apparently I need 50 rep to comment on your question... Regarding putting all ContactInfo records to one line, look into "STUFF" and "FOR XML PATH".

Comment: How can i include UserName in the result?

Comment: I updated the select statement to say "UserName" instead of "Name" from UserInfo table

Comment: Thanks jeffy for your support.