# Select maximum number of repeated UserId in table "ContactInfo" from selected UserId's in "UserInfo" Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My query is like this (Credit @Felix Pamittan)

```
   CREATE TABLE #UserInfo(UserId INT, Name VARCHAR(10));
   CREATE TABLE #ContactInfo(Id INT, UserId INT, Email VARCHAR(20), Mobile VARCHAR(6));

   INSERT INTO #UserInfo VALUES (1, 'Sandeep'), (2, 'James'), (3, 'Vishal');
   INSERT INTO #ContactInfo VALUES (1, 1, 'e1@somemail.com', '111111'), (2, 1, 'e2@somemail.com', '222222'), (3, 3, 'v1@somemail.com', '010101');
  
   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
   SELECT @sql = 
  'SELECT
  u.UserId
 ,u.Name' + CHAR(10)
 SELECT @sql = @sql +
 ',MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), rn) +' THEN t.Email END) AS                  
' + QUOTENAME('Email' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), rn)) + CHAR(10) +
' , MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), rn) +' THEN t.Mobile END) AS ' 
    + QUOTENAME('Mobile' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), rn)) + CHAR(10)
 FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Id)
FROM ContactInfo
     )t
 -- Add filter here for ROW_NUMBER, e.g. starting ffrom the start row to end row
 WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 2

SELECT @sql = @sql +
 'FROM UserInfo u
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT *,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Id)
FROM ContactInfo
 )t
ON t.UserId = u.UserId
-- Add filter here for ROW_NUMBER, e.g. starting from the start row to end row
AND rn BETWEEN 1 AND 2
GROUP BY u.UserId, u.Name
ORDER BY u.UserId, u.Name offset 1 rows FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY'

PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

And my output like this [image]
Now i need to remove Email2 and Mobile2 from my result. For that I need to calculate ROW_NUMBER OF UserId in #ContactInfo from selected UserId from #UserInfo table

you can get [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/448732) here.